# How do I append the contents of numerous files to a single file?

Tags: bash, rtf, cat

I have 44 `RTF` files (`file1.rtf`, `file2.rtf`, `...`, `file44.rtf`) and I need to combine them all into a single file (either `file1.rtf` or a new file altogether).

I understand that the way to combine the contents of two files is like this:

```
cat file2.rtf >> file1.rtf
```

This example appends the contents of `file2.rtf` into `file1.rtf`.

I also understand that I need to iterate through the files, which I can achieve like this:

```
for file in *.rtf;
do
    # do something;
done
```

As such, I have this which appears to do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.rtf;
do
    cat $file >> "../combined.rtf";
    echo "File $file added."
done
```

But there is an issue: when I run `cat ../combined.rtf` I see the combined documents but when I run `open ../combined.rtf` it only shows me the contents of `file1.rtf` (in LibreOffice Writer).

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Maybe the files has carriage returns, no?

Comment: Probably you didn't followed the RTF format. What RTF says about concatenating documents? How it signals the end of the document?

Comment: @Jetchisel Do you mean the script file or the target files?

Comment: Check both of them, just a guess here to root out the possible source of errors.

Comment: @Jetchisel Well the script (`.sh`) file uses `LF` (and not `CRLF`).  The `RTF` files contain carriage returns.

Comment: @Jetchisel Are you suggesting that I might need to remove carriage returns from all of the RTF files in order to get the script to work correctly? If so, how does that explain why I can see the contents via cat ../combined.rtf but why I can't if I open the same file via LibreOffice Writer?

Comment: You'd have to a lot more than line ending stuff. Two rtf files appended together is not a valid rtf file. You'd have to do a more complicated merge taking things like document headers into account.

Comment: All of the above, and you can't rely on `*.rtf` to put `file10.rtf` after `file9.rtf`, it will be right after `file1.rtf`. Rename as `file01.rtf` (etc) and that is one problem solved. Good luck.

Comment: `rtf` is MS format and you need to convert it to simple text first. I would suggest to install ` [catdoc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/catdoc)` it works like `cat` for MS word files.